# Update existing answer or add new one

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

I came out with a pure CSS solution for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21552308/1771795). My old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553307/1771795) is accepted and upvoted but it uses jQuery as a solution.

The new answer will definitely *invalidate* the old one as it is much better than it. Therefore, I am uncertain whether I should...

- Update existing answer
- Overwrite existing answer
- Add new answer and keep old one
- Add new answer and delete old one

If you happen to encounter such case, what would you do?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to do (c); add a new answer, then add an "update" sentence to the original answer, pointing people to your new solution. You won't be able to delete your old answer anyway, since it's accepted (nor do I think you should, anyway).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add new answer and add a comment that this answer is valid for the reason which are relevant to specify.

Make sure to specify that the old one is valid for the timeline (or changes) and new one which is now onwards and give a reason for that.