# Edit adds new content to answer that updates for a new version of language

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers, suggested-edits

I was going through the edit queue and found this edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23754211

It adds new content, but doesn't seem to be against the original intent of the author.  The original author added code for swift 3.0, this is just updated code for 4.2, but keeps the old code as well.  I don't think adding a new answer is that great because there appear to be a *loooot* of answers on that question, all with various amounts of up-votes, several having more than 10, so I don't see it likely that the editor would get their answer seen by people who need it unless they edited this answer.

At the same time, I'm not sure what the consensus is on these types of edits.  If the original author did this, people would be fine, but it seems precedent is to create a [new answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277265/update-existing-answer-or-add-new-one).  If that's what we want people to do fine, hopefully people would see the comment, but what do *I* do here?  If I reject the edit, this information may be lost, so how do I ensure a new answer is created if that's what Meta wants? (I'm not an expert in swift, so *I* can't do it, and that also seems unfair to the editor).

Comment: Although editing a post to add updates as a post ages is a reason outlined in the editing help, by putting a new version answer into the answer, suddenly this unverified and untested code appears to have received 13 upvotes from the community. As an editor or reviewer, I don't think 1 user's claim that some code works great is good enough to merit the unintentional support of 13 people who already supported the existing code.

Comment: @DavyM  That's a very good point, would you mind putting that in an answer?

Comment: I actually [already have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362673/7795130). :)

Answer (score 5):

This edit should be rejected (and now has been), it falls under the reject reason:

> This edit was **intended to address the author of the post** and makes no sense as an edit. **It should have been written as** a comment or **an answer**. <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

I've [pinged the editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680649/zooming-mkmapview-to-fit-annotation-pins/45557164#comment101344994_45557164) (possible as they left a comment) to let them know that if they want to provide a new answer, then they should write an answer, not edit it into an existing post.

Suggested edits which introduce new versions of code into an answer should be rejected as they should be fully fledged answers.

---

It's not your responsibility to worry about the lost information, but if you wanted to you *could* take the added content and put it into a community wiki answer with a reference to the suggested edits provided in the comments. It can then be left to rise/fall/be deleted alongside the other answers.

I would however recommend just forgetting about it, if the editor wants to add an answer they can review their rejected edits and see the review comment.

Comment: Okay, that's a good answer, I didn't realize I even had the power to create a community wiki post.

Comment: @opa There's a little checkbox to the bottom right of the answer text field, I wouldn't use it *too* frequently though